# vs 2015 and vs 2017 powershell interactive window hangs

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Installed powershell tools for visual studio, but the powershell interactive window hangs with this message:

'Please wait while the PowerShell host is initialized. This may take a few moments..."

Tried setting the ExecutionPolicy for powershell, but does not work.

The weird part is, I have visual studios installed on a personal laptop and the powershell interactive window works fine. It's my work computer that it's not working on.

Not sure if it's something to do with it being on a network, network security of some kind or what?

Comment: 1. What version of PSH do you have (content of `$psversiontable`)? 2. Do you have anything in your profile?

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                             windows 7 on work laptop,     windows 10 on personal laptop

Comment: Any input would be appreciated?